# What does "spread" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

From the movie [Lucky Number Slevin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Number_Slevin):

> So you go to the ticket window with your 20 grand in hand and you get 9 to 1 **if the spread sticks**.

It's about horse racing. I can't seem to find a definition in any online dictionary that would fit in the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***If the spread sticks***: If what you bet would happen will happen

Why a dictionary? Search for betting spread:

https://www.sbo.net/horse-racing/spread-betting-on-horse-racing/

> What is Spread Betting?
>   The main difference between fixed odds betting and spread betting is that generally the more right you are, the more money you make. Fixed odds betting typically works with a predetermined return on the stake, however the liability or profit can vary when taking part in spread betting according to the accuracy of the bet.
>
> Spread betting companies will compile a list of different markets for each horse racing meeting every day. They will offer a prediction for each market and the challenge is for the customer to determine whether the outcome will be higher or lower than predicted. If as a punter you believe that the outcome would be higher, then you would ‘buy’ and if you believed it would be lower you would ‘sell’. If you agreed with the prediction then it would make sense not to have a bet. When trying to compare it to fixed odds betting, spread betting would be closest to totals betting or over/under markets.

And as for the use in Slevin:

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Headscratchers/LuckyNumberSlevin